# Computed properties in vue not reflected in select list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a vue component that is meant to create a select list with all available options. The `save` method puts the saved value into a `vuex` store. The available fields are generated using a computed property on the component that calls the vuex getter for the list.

In the component, there's a `v-for` with a `v-if` that checks that the select item isn't already being used by another component (by looking at a `mapped` property on the list item object).

Testing this, everything seems to be working as expected, the vuex store gets the list, it accepts the update, and once a save is called, the destination field is marked as `mapped` and that mapped property is visible in the vuex debug panel.

However, the other select lists on the page don't get updated to reflect the (now shorter) list of available options.

Once the select item is selected in another instance of the component, I'd expect the other components to drop that select option- but it appears the `v-if` is not re-evaluated after the initial load of the component?

Sorry, here's the basic component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            {{ item.source_id }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <select v-model="destination" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <option v-for="dest in destinationFields" v-if="shouldShow(dest)" v-bind:value="dest.id">{{ dest.id }} - {{ dest.label }} ({{ dest.dataType }})</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['item'],
    data() {
        return {
            destination: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        shouldShow: function(dest) {
            if (this.hideDestination && (!dest.hasOwnProperty('mapped') || dest.id === this.destination)) {
                return true
            } else if (!this.hideDestination) {
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        destinationFields: function() {
            return this.$store.getters.visibleDestination
        },
        hideDestination: function() {
            return this.$store.getters.hideMappedDestinations // boolean 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of code?

Comment: @connexo-- code sample added. thanks

Comment: give a try to move shouldShow from method to computed for v-if. because shouldSHow is only run once at init.

Comment: @sphinx-- I don't believe you're allowed to pass parameters to a computed property, and I need to evaluate each list item for visibility

Comment: @user101289 you can caculate ishow in `destinationFields: function() {}`, then add the result to `this.$store.getters.visibleDestination.isshow`, finally, bind `v-if="dest.isshow"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to already filter the data inside of your computed function as follows:

```
computed: {
    destinationFields: function() {
        return this.$store.getters.visibleDestination()
            .filter(dest => !dest.hasOwnProperty('mapped') || dest.id === this.destination)
    },
    hideDestination: function() {
        return this.$store.getters.hideMappedDestinations // boolean 
    }
}
```

You would also have to change your template to:

```
<select v-model="destination" class="form-control form-control-sm">
    <option v-for="dest in destinationFields" v-bind:value="dest.id">{{ dest.id }} - {{ dest.label }} ({{ dest.dataType }})</option>
</select>
```